# SQL Server: Two Level Sort (Order/Group By??)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Everyone:

I have the following code which produced the below table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[Date]
               ,a.[ID]
               ,a.[Account]
               ,a.[First_Last]
FROM [Table] AS a
WHERE [First_Last] = 1 OR
      [First_Last] = (
                        SELECT MAX([First_Last])
                        FROM [Table] AS b
                        WHERE a.[ID] = b.[ID] AND a.[Account] = b.[Account]
                       )
ORDER BY [ID], [Account], [Date]
```

```
Date        ID      Account  First_Last
10/31/2018  1111    45       1
1/29/2021   1111    45       4
9/29/2017   1111    753      1
9/28/2018   1111    753      2
9/29/2017   2222    481      1
1/31/2018   2222    481      2
10/31/2017  2222    488      1
1/31/2018   2222    488      2
11/30/2017  2222    582      1
1/31/2019   2222    582      3
2/28/2017   2222    621      1
2/28/2018   2222    621      2
6/30/2017   2222    1007     1
6/29/2018   2222    1007     2
```

But I need it to be ordered this way:

```
Date        ID      Account  First_Last
9/29/2017   1111    753      1
9/28/2018   1111    753      2
10/31/2018  1111    45       1
1/29/2021   1111    45       4
2/28/2017   2222    621      1
2/28/2018   2222    621      2
6/30/2017   2222    1007     1
6/29/2018   2222    1007     2
9/29/2017   2222    481      1
1/31/2018   2222    481      2
10/31/2017  2222    488      1
1/31/2018   2222    488      2
11/30/2017  2222    582      1
1/31/2019   2222    582      3
```

Notice that the table I need is not sorted by `Account`.  It is sorted by Date for each `ID`-`Account` combination.  For example, for ID = 1111, Account 753 comes before Account 45 because 753's first date is 9/29/2017 and 45's first date is 10/31/2018.  Since I do not want `Account` to be sorted, I tried to remove `Account` from the `ORDER BY`, but that put the `Account` numbers in random lines because of `Date` instead of grouping them together.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function to find the "first date" by `ID` and `Account`.

```
order by ID, 
         min([Date]) over(partition by ID, Account), 
         [Date]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know we can do that in an Order By statement.

Comment: One additional question.  How do I go about adding row numbers to this sorted table?  I have tried `ROW_NUMBER` in various forms, but have not found on that works.

Comment: It is better to ask a new question on the `ROW_NUMBER` issue. Please do include sample data and required result together with your query