# Add LAG or ROW_NUMBER into an Unusually Sorted Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, lag, row-number

I had previously asked a question about how to sort by table in an unusual way ([SQL Server: Two Level Sort (Order/Group By??)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73535752/sql-server-two-level-sort-order-group-by)).  I have added the solution to my code:

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[ID]
      ,[Account]
      ,[First_Last]
FROM [Table]
ORDER BY [ID], MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account], [ID]), [Account], [Date]
```

```
Date        ID      Account  First_Last
9/29/2017   1111    753      1
9/28/2018   1111    753      2
10/31/2018  1111    45       1
1/29/2021   1111    45       4
2/28/2017   2222    621      1
2/28/2018   2222    621      2
6/30/2017   2222    1007     1
6/29/2018   2222    1007     2
9/29/2017   2222    481      1
1/31/2018   2222    481      2
10/31/2017  2222    488      1
1/31/2018   2222    488      2
11/30/2017  2222    582      1
1/31/2019   2222    582      3
```

Now, I want to add change flags that signal when `Account` changes, but whenever I try `LAG` or `ROW_NUMBER` the `ORDER BY` statement is giving me trouble.  If I use:

```
[Account] <> LAG([Account]) OVER (ORDER BY [ID], MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account], [ID]), [Account], [Date])
```

It shows me this error:

> Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

But if I don't use a different `ORDER BY` without a window function, `Account` is being compared to an incorrect number instead of the previous one such as:

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[ID]
      ,[Account]
      ,[First_Last]
      ,CASE WHEN[Account] <> LAG([Account]) OVER (ORDER BY [Account]) THEN '1' END AS [Acct_Chg]
FROM [Table]
ORDER BY [ID], MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account], [ID]), [Account], [Date]
```

Which resulted in this:

```
Date        ID      Account  First_Last  Acct_Chg
9/29/2017   1111    753      1           
9/28/2018   1111    753      2           
10/31/2018  1111    45       1           
1/29/2021   1111    45       4           1
2/28/2017   2222    621      1           1
2/28/2018   2222    621      2
6/30/2017   2222    1007     1           
6/29/2018   2222    1007     2           1
9/29/2017   2222    481      1           
1/31/2018   2222    481      2
10/31/2017  2222    488      1           
1/31/2018   2222    488      2           1
11/30/2017  2222    582      1           1
1/31/2019   2222    582      3
```

Which is incorrect.

Ultimately, what I am looking for is this:

```
Date        ID      Account  First_Last  Acct_Chg
9/29/2017   1111    753      1           
9/28/2018   1111    753      2           
10/31/2018  1111    45       1           1
1/29/2021   1111    45       4
2/28/2017   2222    621      1           1
2/28/2018   2222    621      2
6/30/2017   2222    1007     1           1
6/29/2018   2222    1007     2
9/29/2017   2222    481      1           1
1/31/2018   2222    481      2
10/31/2017  2222    488      1           1
1/31/2018   2222    488      2
11/30/2017  2222    582      1           1
1/31/2019   2222    582      3
```

I don't know of I can just do this with `LAG` or whether I need `ROW_NUMBER`, but I could not get either to work the way I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I tried:

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[ID]
      ,[Account]
      ,[First_Last]
      ,CASE WHEN [Account] <> LAG([Account]) OVER (ORDER BY [Account], [Date] DESC) THEN '1' END AS [Acct_Chg]
FROM [Table]
ORDER BY [ID], MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account], [ID]), [Account], [Date]
```

And got this:

```
Date        ID      Account  First_Last  Acct_Chg
9/29/2017   1111    753      1           
9/28/2018   1111    753      2           
10/31/2018  1111    45       1
1/29/2021   1111    45       4           1
2/28/2017   2222    621      1           
2/28/2018   2222    621      2
6/30/2017   2222    1007     1           
6/29/2018   2222    1007     2
9/29/2017   2222    481      1           
1/31/2018   2222    481      2
10/31/2017  2222    488      1           
1/31/2018   2222    488      2           1
11/30/2017  2222    582      1           
1/31/2019   2222    582      3           1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this did not work.

Comment: Give us the DDL+DML or a DBFiddle so we can have a go without having to type out all your data.

Comment: I don't understand.  I thought that's what I did.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thank you for your attention.  I was about to post the DDL/DML when I think I figured out a workaround.

Comment: Well make sure you post your solution below as an answer in that case/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found out that you cannot window function inside another window function.

The workaround is the use `CTE` and find the `MINDATE` `MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account], [ID])` inside the CTE. Then on the outer query you can use the `LAG()` as per normal.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Date]
          ,[ID]
          ,[Account]
          ,[First_Last]
          ,MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account], [ID]) AS [MINDATE]
    FROM  [Table]
)
SELECT [Date]
      ,[ID]
      ,[Account]
      ,[First_Last]
      ,CASE WHEN [Account] <> LAG([Account]) OVER (ORDER BY [ID], [MINDATE], [Account], [Date]) 
            THEN '1' 
            END AS [Acct_Chg]
FROM   CTE
ORDER BY [ID], [MINDATE], [Account], [Date]
```

Comment: Thank you!  Turns out my workaround did not completely work so I needed this after all. Next time I ask a question, I do my best to post the DDL/DML.